# Why when I save a collection inside a doc inside a collection I got a long random number (id of somewhat) in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, ionic4

I save some data into firebase using this code

```
  this.afs.collection('USERS').doc('UID').collection('Monday').add(this.submitValue);
```

Then inside my database, I have a number (id of somewhat) between my collection name and my value that I saved.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation for [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add).  It says:

> Add a new document to this collection with the specified data, **assigning it a document ID automatically.**

What you are seeing is the automatically generated ID.  If you would rather assign your own unique ID, then use [doc(id)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) to generate a reference to save the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set an ID, you can use the `.set()` method, as so:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({...})
```

This results a document with the ID 'LA' int the `cities` collection.

For more information check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)